# Resolve special character (é,@,ç etc..) in Angular

Tags: html, angular

How can I resolve the print of special character in Angular (see in file attachment)?

In my index.html, I define :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>LoginCCPD</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
 </head>
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>  
   </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Where is the data not being displayed correctly coming from? To start with, make sure your file is being served as UTF-8.

Comment: It is just a menu text .. not data provided from database or other..;

Comment: I solved it by modifying eclipse configuration